# How to add dynamic table list to a Full calendar page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I have implemented a Fullcalendar on a RoR page.
I would like to add a list (index) below the calendar showing events for the day the user selects.  Click on a day and that days events list below the calendar.  I'd like it to be dynamic (don't reload the whole page).

Please point me in the right direction to learn how to do this.
I have a subscription to Railscast.  But, I'm not sure what to look for.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make a javascript function , that listens to the click event of 'tb' in Fullcalendar . It should trigger ajax call to fetch events from the database , filtered by date . [This Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised) is a very nice example how ajax calls refresh some page content without reloading the whole page .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dayClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) callback to call an ajax function which populates your index/list